# Can I create, own & run a Dating website?

Tags: fiqh, shiism, shia-sunni, shia-imam

**Asslamu-un-Alakum**

I was wondering if I can provide a matrimonial service (known as dating sites) to the users? If I wanna launch a site just for Muslim brother and sisters who are seeking a partner. Am I allowed to do it in Islam? Specially I greatly appreciate an answer according to "Shia" Fiqh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I appreciate your endeavor for making such useful site as you remarked:

> i wanna launch a site just for Muslim brother and sisters who are
>   seeking a partner

Secondly it won't be haram by itself, as can reach many couples to each others (by getting marriage), but the significant point is that it can be a place for haram acts as well, by relations which can be result in non-Islamic relationship by making relationship between boys and girls... And actually some or many individuals can misuse ...

For instance (as you asked for Shia), there is such problem in Iran (as a Shi'ite country) as well. That at majority of times they avoid doing such sites due to its side problems which can have many negative points too. So, as a recommendation: you can do this goal by being broker (mediator) to introduce the appropriate cases to each other...

توکلت علی الله